# XSLT counting child nodes with a set of filter

Tags: xslt, count, nodes

I want to remove all spaces with normalize space() while counting all nodes and use a Filter on those.

What I want is something like this:

```
<{namespace}:Text>
  <{namespace}:Info>This is text from Info Node</{namespace}:Info>
  Here is text which i want to find
</{namespace}:Text>
```

I want to count all children from {namespace}:Text , but i want to ignore {namespace}:Info and [namespace}:otherelement and the content of those should be ignored too.
I want as a result from count a 1 so that I know there are nodes which I have to process, so I can call templates workwithcontent or workwithempty.

But of course I do want to find other nodes too which don't fit the filter.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like

```
<xsl:template match="{namespace}:Text">
  <xsl:variable name="count"
          select="count(child::node()[not(self::{namespace}:Info)])" />
  ...
```

This will count all child nodes of `<{namespace}:Text>`, including both text and element nodes, except for `<{namespace}:Info>` elements.

If that's not what you need, please clarify.

The `child::` axis is optional, but makes it more obvious what the XPath expression will select.